# Using Composer packages in a FuelPHP app managed with GitHub

Tags: php, git, github, fuelphp

I have a web application that I built using FuelPHP which is hosted on a private GitHub repo.

I recently added [JAXL](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL) and [APNS-PHP](https://github.com/varavan/ApnsPHP) to the project [using Composer](http://fuelphp.com/blogs/2013/01/fuelphp-and-composer). Specifically, I created a `composer.json` inside of the `fuel/app` directory with these contents:

```
{
    "require": {
        "varavan/apns-php": "dev-master",
        "abhinavsingh/jaxl": "3.*@dev"
    }
}
```

I ran `composer update` and everything works fine on my local development environment. I can push to GitHub just fine from the command line also.

However, when I `pull` on the public server, the newly installed composer packages are not included in the pull, although their directories are created. Specifically, these directories exist, but are empty:

```
fuel/app/vendor/abhinavsingh/jaxl/
fuel/app/vendor/varavan/apns-php/
```

If I look at those directories on GitHub, they don't look like directories. They've got an icon that I don't recognize:

[image: This is what the directories look like on GitHub]

<s>Also, if I click on "Sync Branch" from the GitHub GUI app, it gives me this message</s> This has been resolved, see update below.

> The submodule at 'fuel/app/vendor/abhinavsingh/jaxl' was removed from
>   .gitmodules, but the folder still exists in the repositroy. Delete the
>   folder, commit the change, then try again.

## WHAT!?

I used composer to install JAXL, not Git.

If I run `composer install` on the server, it says:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

But the JAXL and APNS-PHP directories are still empty.

How do I get the composer packages onto my production server?

## Update

I added this to my `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "fuel/app/vendor/abhinavsingh/jaxl"]
        path = fuel/app/vendor/abhinavsingh/jaxl
        url = git://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL.git
[submodule "fuel/app/vendor/varavan/apns-php"]
        path = fuel/app/vendor/varavan/apns-php
        url = git://github.com/varavan/ApnsPHP.git
```

That fixed the error that the GitHub GUI app was giving me, but I still can't figure out how to get the composer packages installed on the production server.

Comment: Why would you push the composer managed packages in the first place?

Comment: I didn't specifically attempt to push the composer managed packages, I just ran a `git push` and a `git pull` and everything broke. I'm just trying to get things sorted out.

Comment: Do u have a .git directory inside apns-php/ and jaxl/

Comment: On my local machine, yes, I have `.git` directories in both the `apns-php` and `jaxl` directories. On the production server, there is nothing in those directories.

Comment: You’re supposed to add your **vendor** directory to your **.gitignore** file. The packages installed by Composer should *not* be pushed to GitHub; just run `composer install` when you clone the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to try everything I could think of to get the composer packages loaded, but I couldn't figure it out.

After adding the submodule definitions to my `.gitmodules` file, I deleted the entire project from the production server and re-cloned the whole thing from GitHub. The submodules came along for the ride.

It's not the composer way of doing things...

## Whatever. What a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Composer uses git, especially if you specify you want a development version. It will get it directly from the source.

And if you create a second vendor folder inside app, and Composer has added a git repository there (because of what you specified), git will detect a repo-in-repo, and since submodules are active for Fuel, it will assume you're adding a new submodule.

Like Martin Bean said, make sure you exclude the vendor folder, to prevent this from happening.